# Programmatically generate .generated.cs from an EDMX in an CCNET automated build process

Tags: build-automation, cruisecontrol.net, edmx

I'm trying to use CCNET to automatically build an MVC Project using EDMX.
We don't save the generated files in the source control (such as the files created by the EDMX when you open it and save(.generated.cs)), so those have to be regenerated in the build process, but they are not. I'm using MVC4 and CCNET is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [TextTransform Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) installed in the build server. A good guidance on code generation for build server can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423.aspx).